# AND field NOT IN(NULL) returns an empty set

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does this query returns an empty set:

```
select p.iuser_id,p.produit_id from portefeuille p
WHERE produit_id=48
AND p.iuser_id NOT IN (NULL);
```

whereas this one :

```
select p.iuser_id,p.produit_id from portefeuille p
WHERE produit_id=48
LIMIT 5
```

return results like

```
72968, 48
106967, 48
7381, 48
81678, 48
194250, 48
```

and none of those values are NULL or should be equal to NULL.
(I added limit 5 for consiseness, and I am using MySql 5.1)

---

edit: Here I narrowed the problem down to NOT IN(NULL). The original query had a subquery with some of the rows containing NULL as such:

```
WHERE user_id NOT IN( select user_id from mailsubscriptions )
```

and some user_id were NULL, but only one NULL in the set contaminates the whole query.

Comment: Not sure on MySql, but *both* `NULL <> NULL` and `NULL = NULL` are `false` on some engines.

Comment: @MatthiasMeid Pedantic correction: both `NULL <> NULL` and `NULL = NULL` result in `UNKNOWN` (not `FALSE`) in MySQL and all DBMS that try to be ANSI/ISO SQL compliant. The result is the same of course in `WHERE` clauses because only rows that have the condition evaluated as `TRUE` are returned.

Comment: I'll give you +1 for the **"only one NULL in the set contaminates the whole query."**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

x NOT IN (...) is defined as a series of comparisons between x and each of the values returned by the subquery. SQL uses three-value logic, for which the three possible values of a logical expression are *true*, *false* or *unknown*. Comparison of a value to a NULL is *unknown* and if any one of those NOT IN comparisons is *unknown* then the result is also deemed to be *unknown*.

Comment: can you explain what is the comparision generated? from your answer I would say x NOT IN(S) is equivalent to : x<>S1 && x<>s2 ... && x<>sn. Am I right ?

Comment: @BiAiB yes you are right.. If you say X IN (S) it's the same as `X=s1 or x=s1 or ...`

Comment: Well, thank you then, that answered my question best.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing with null is always a bad idea. Even `NULL = NULL` or `NULL <> NULL` will return NULL.

Use `IS NOT NULL` insetad

In your case the query is identical to:

```
select p.iuser_id,p.produit_id from portefeuille p
WHERE produit_id=48
AND p.iuser_id <> NULL;
```

and the value of `p.iuser_id <> NULL`  will be NULL regardless of the value of `p.isuer_id` and this explains why it returns an empty set!

Comment: The result of NULL=NULL and NULL<>NULL style comparisons is always *unknown* and never *false*. Big difference, and that's why the query returns the result it does.

Comment: you are right, unknown or null and when evaluating in an if it is equal to false, it means the record would not be shown..

Comment: I already got that it's a bad idea, but your answer doesn't explain(or at least I don't understand how your answer would) why the returned set is empty.

Comment: because if you say `i_userid in (NULL)` it is the same as saying `i_userid = NULL` which would be always NULL regardless of the value of i_userid

Answer (score 1):

Any comparison to NULL, with the exception of `is null` and `is not null`, returns NULL which is interpreted as false for boolean purposes.  This is standard behavior for all databaes.

If you want to do a comparison within a set of values, here are two options:

```
where coalesce(produit_id, -1) not in (-1, . . . .)
```

This assumes that -1 is an invalid value for the id.  Or, you can do an explicit comparison:

```
where produit_id is not null and produit_id not in ( . . . )
```

Comment: Are you sure about your second proposal? I think it will return no rows either.

Comment: @ypercube . . . It won't return NULL values but it should return other values.

Comment: Even if there is a `NULL` in the `...` list?

Answer (score 0):

dont compare NULL  with NULL

you need to specify `IS NOT NULL` here

Comment: where is there a comparison with two NULL ? the only NULL is in the NOT IN() set