# How to avoid timeout when deleting childless parent records using DELETE... WHERE NOT IN (SELECT)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a many-one relationship between two very large MySQL tables as follows:

trips -> trippolylines

```
trips
==========================
BIGINT(20) trippolyline_id

trippolylines
=====================
BIGINT(20) id
```

The Foreign key relationship is 'On Delete: SET NULL':

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_trips_trippolylines_id1` FOREIGN KEY (`trippolyline_id`) REFERENCES `trippolylines` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

I want to delete all childless parent records in the `trippolylines` table - I'm not aware of a way to do this via cascade deletion (is there one?) - so I'm using this query:

```
DELETE FROM trippolylines WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT trippolyline_id from trips);
```

The problem is that it keeps timing out with

```
18:24:51    Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  600.008 sec
```

after 10 minutes.

I could increase the timeout - but before I do, is there a more efficient way to be handling this scenario?

## Solution

(V2)

Thanks to a combination of comments below and the answer from Ike Walker, the solution was to optimise the DELETE query by using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a subquery, as follows:

```
DELETE trippolylines FROM trippolylines
LEFT JOIN trips ON id = trippolyline_id
WHERE trip_id IS NULL;
```

This runs significantly faster (i.e. at least x10, haven't measured precise speed-up) and completed in around 80seconds.

I suspect I could further optimise this new query to run in batches.

Comment: Try `not exists (select 1 from trips where trips.trippolyline_id = trippolylines.id)` Not sure I would expect this to make a difference on other platforms but I think MySQL isn't as adept at rewriting queries.

Comment: What I've seen is that `NOT EXISTS` doesn't perform as well as `NOT IN` or `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` for MySQL, but it's always worth a try. Your specific data could cause one method to outperform the others even if it doesn't in most situations.

Comment: @Carlos P Have you considered doing this in batches? Filter on `id` between various ranges of numbers, incrementing until the entire table is processed?

Comment: If `trips.trippolyline_id` is allowed to be NULL, then your query has a logic error.  You need to say either `(SELECT trippolyline_id from trips where trippolyline_id IS NOT NULL)` or use a  NOT EXISTS expression.  NOT IN (SELECT ....) when there are nulls in the subquery [will always evaluate to UNKNOWN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038414/and-field-not-innull-returns-an-empty-set) because of how NOT IN unrolls.  You can also delete in batches to give the query more time to exectute.  Put an `ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100` in your DELETE query and re-execute it until everything is gone.

Comment: I've had similar performance problems with MySQL and for one-time clean-up and migration operations, creating a temporary table speeds things up a lot. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_del (SELECT trippolyline_id FROM trips);`. Don't forget to drop it, afterwards.

Comment: @BaconBits - good catch, thank you.  The batch deletion enabled me to proceed, but was still very slow.  In the end I optimised the query using `LEFT JOIN...WHERE IS NOT NULL` and it ran significantly faster - see updated question.

Comment: Are you sure that is what you men to do.  That is dangerous looking delete to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid a timeout with a long-running delete query like that is to do one or both of the following:

1. Optimize the delete query
2. Break the delete into multiple smaller chunks

For #1, depending on the version of MySQL you are running you may find faster performance using an exclusion join or a `NOT EXISTS` query as opposed to using `NOT IN`.

For #2, I usually use [common_schema](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema) to break the delete into multiple chunks. Here's a blog post I wrote on that topic: http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/11/24/alternatives-for-chunking-bulk-deletes-in-common-schema/

Comment: I didn't want to use a 3rd party library, but optimising the query using an exclusion join has massively helped - I've updated the question with the full answer.

Comment: @CarlosP I'm glad my answer was helpful. However, I'm concerned that the solution you came up with may not be doing what you want it to do. Typically "orphaned records" means child rows that don't reference a valid parent row. Your original delete statement instead deleted "childless parents" -- parent rows that were not referenced by any child rows. On the other hand, your solution is neither deleting "orphans" nor "childless parents", instead it is deleting all parent rows that are referenced by 1 or more child rows. I think this is *not* what you want to do.

Comment: you're absolutely right, good catch.  I have amended my solution above with what I believe is the correct answer, but I would be grateful if you'd take a quick look and drop me a comment.  I am unclear exactly what counts as 'parent' or 'child' here, but essentially a `trip` record can reference either 0 or 1 `trippolyline` record.  So I guess there is a one-to-many relationship from `trippolyline` to `trip`.  What I want to do is delete all `trippolyline` records that are not referenced by any `trip` records.

Comment: @CarlosP that looks better. Your updated delete is functionally equivalent to your original delete, so that should be what you want. Your parent table is `trippolylines`, and your child table is `trips`. Therefore you are technically deleting "childless parents", not "orphans".

Comment: Thanks for that, I shall amend my question description too so it's not confusing for others.