# MySQL - Return a list of members only if they are not in another list

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a list of members only if they are not in another list. When the other list has at least one member then the query works (member not in the other list are returned). However, when the other list contains no members (returns NULL) then no values are returned.

```
String selectQry = ("SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id, at_cub_details.cd_surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name, " +
            "at_cub_details.cd_archived " +
            "FROM at_cub_details, at_account_group " + 
            "WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = ? AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id " +
                "AND ( " +
                    " SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id " +
                          "FROM at_group, at_account_group group1, at_account_group group2, at_accounts " + 
                          "LEFT JOIN at_account_cub_association ON at_accounts.acc_id = at_account_cub_association.acc_id " +
                          "LEFT JOIN at_cub_details ON at_account_cub_association.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id " +
                          "WHERE (at_accounts.acc_id = ? " +
                            "AND (group1.acc_id = ?  " +
                            "AND group1.grp_id = group2.grp_id " +
                            "AND group2.acc_id = at_accounts.acc_id)) " +
                            "AND (group2.grp_id = at_group.grp_id) LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL " +
                "AND at_cub_details.cd_id NOT IN ( " +
                                " SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id " +
                                      "FROM at_group, at_account_group group1, at_account_group group2, at_accounts " + 
                                      "LEFT JOIN at_account_cub_association ON at_accounts.acc_id = at_account_cub_association.acc_id " +
                                      "LEFT JOIN at_cub_details ON at_account_cub_association.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id " +
                                      "WHERE (at_accounts.acc_id = ? " +
                                        "AND (group1.acc_id = ?  " +
                                        "AND group1.grp_id = group2.grp_id " +
                                        "AND group2.acc_id = at_accounts.acc_id)) " +
                                        "AND (group2.grp_id = at_group.grp_id)) " +
            "ORDER BY at_cub_details.cd_surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name;");
```

OK, to simplify the second and third "SELECT" works the first "SELECT" only works when the third "SELECT" returns a value not when it returns "NULL". Initially I only had the third "SELECT". I then added the second "SELECT" to check for "NULL" first. However, that did not correct the issue. So:

This works:

```
String selectQry = ("SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id, at_cub_details.cd_surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name, " +
            "at_cub_details.cd_archived " +
            "FROM at_cub_details, at_account_group " + 
            "WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = ? AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id " +
                "AND at_cub_details.cd_id NOT IN ( '20' ) " +
            "ORDER BY at_cub_details.cd_surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name;");
```

This does not work:

```
String selectQry = ("SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id, at_cub_details.cd_surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name, " +
            "at_cub_details.cd_archived " +
            "FROM at_cub_details, at_account_group " + 
            "WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = ? AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id " +
                "AND at_cub_details.cd_id NOT IN ( NULL ) " +
            "ORDER BY at_cub_details.cd_surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name;");
```

As to whether you down vote me or not, I do not really care as I am doing this not for profit and learning as I go (I am not a programmer).

Comment: Well that was a quick down vote. I am sure it is against the rules of this forum to down vote without giving a reason.

Comment: There is an uncomfortable number of mixed implicit and explicit joins here. It would probably be a good idea to replace all the implicit joins with explicit joins before attempting to debug this lump of code.

Comment: They wouldn't have designed the forum that way if that were the case. Anyway, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Just throwing out query is not enough; provide table structures, sample data and expected output. Also, you need to minimize your problem statement to relevant portions only.

Comment: No, it is absolutely not against the rules to downvote without comments. See the following meta discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038414/and-field-not-innull-returns-an-empty-set) to understand the reason why MySQL returns nothing on a `NOT IN (NULL)` expression or result. The reason why you get downvoted is that your question doesn't fit a good SQL question. You should show the "pure" SQL queries and not Java or other language aggregated strings. You should show your tables' structure and you should show actual and expected data., and maybe also the EXPLAIN PLAN. And it is especially necessary with questions on complex queries like you have there.

Comment: It is YOUR duty to format your question rightly so we can understand it without struggling to decipher your string-aggregated non-SQL code. PS: I did not downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The people at CodeRanch have been very helpful. The answer is to use "IFNULL" to return 0 if null instead of checking for NULL.

```
String selectQry = ("SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id, at_cub_details.cd_surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name, " +
                "at_cub_details.cd_archived " +
                "FROM at_cub_details, at_account_group " + 
                "WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = ? AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id " +
                    "AND at_cub_details.cd_id NOT IN ( " +
                                    "SELECT IFNULL (at_cub_details.cd_id, 0) " +
                                          "FROM at_group, at_account_group group1, at_account_group group2, at_accounts " + 
                                          "LEFT JOIN at_account_cub_association ON at_accounts.acc_id = at_account_cub_association.acc_id " +
                                          "LEFT JOIN at_cub_details ON at_account_cub_association.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id " +
                                          "WHERE (at_accounts.acc_id = ? " +
                                            "AND (group1.acc_id = ?  " +
                                            "AND group1.grp_id = group2.grp_id " +
                                            "AND group2.acc_id = at_accounts.acc_id)) " +
                                            "AND (group2.grp_id = at_group.grp_id)) " +
                "ORDER BY at_cub_details.cd_surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name;");
```

Kind regards,

Glyn