# NOT IN returns wrong results with where

Tags: sql, mysql, not-exists, notin

i am new in MYSQL and i am asking for help which NOT IN function is not working

```
select * 
from `oc_order` 
where `customer_id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `customer_id` 
    FROM `oc_order` 
    WHERE `order_status_id` LIKE "3" 
      AND `last_update` > '2022-12-28' 
      AND `customer_id` > 0 
      AND `customer_group_id` > 0
    );
```

I need to find out customers who are not active during this year. Could you please give me some solution for solve this problem? thanks

i checked inside NOT IN is working fine:

```
SELECT `customer_id` 
FROM `oc_order` 
WHERE `order_status_id` LIKE "3" 
  AND `last_update` > '2022-12-28' 
  AND `customer_id` > 0 
  AND `customer_group_id` > 0
```

Comment: *NOT IN function is not working* It cannot "not work". You may receive the output which differs from desired one or an error. Maybe your subquery returns the row(s) with NULL value? Provide sample data which reproduces the issue according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: When you have one of the NULL `customer_id` in `NOT IN ()` query then you get empty result. Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038414/and-field-not-innull-returns-an-empty-set

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: You could write this as a `NOT EXISTS` instead, but to be honest it's probably better using window functions `select * from (select *, count(case when order_status_id LIKE "3" AND last_update > '2022-12-28' AND customer_id > 0 AND customer_group_id > 0 then 1 end) over (partition by customer_id) as count from oc_order) c where count = 0;`

Comment: I have re-opened the request, because this is obviously not about `NOT IN` not working when a subquery returns nulls, as `AND customer_id > 0` prevents the subquery from producing nulls. I have added an answer that hopefully explains minor issues with the query and how to really approach the problem. @Simon_Sam: Never say "is not working"; always tell us what is happening instead of the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find out customers who are not active during this year.

Your query doesn't match this description. First of all, you should be selecting from a customer table, because inactive customers may not even have an entry in the order table that you are using in your query.

Then you define the year 2023 to start after midnight of December 28, 2012, which is somewhat special :-) And you declare a customer "active" when they have an order that was updated in that time (so every update means activity on the part of the customer?) and the order status matching some string expression. Also, the customer ID must be greater than zero and the customer group ID, too.

Can an order really be assigned to a negative customer ID? Or is this to avoid unassigned orders (customer ID NULL)? Are such orders even possible? And what does the customer group ID in the order table represent? Why is the customer not assigned a group in the customer table? Can a customer belong to a different group with each order, or what else is it that the group ID is supposed to mean here? `order_status_id LIKE "3"` is a weird expression by the way. First of all you should use standard string delimiters, which is the single quote, not the double quote. Then you are using `LIKE` without any pattern (`%` or `_`), so why not use `=` right away? And is the status ID really a string, anyway? A date literal should start with the word `DATE` by the way to be compliant with standard SQL.

The query that I would expect would look something like this:

```
select *
from customer c
where not exists
(
  select null
  from oc_order o
  where o.customer_id = c.customer_id
  and o.order_status_id = 3
  and o.last_update > date '2022-12-28'
)
order by c.customer_id;
```

While this may not completely answer all your questions, it should be sufficient to solve your struggles with the query.